# Ho do i create edges like the one used on the corner of this object

Tags: modeling, edges, bevel

I am very new to Blender and 3D and have watched lots of videos which never show how to create a corner like the one in this picture.

Could someone tell me the best way to re-create it?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You have to select the edge, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> , that way you bevel the edge.

If then you want to replicate the difference in length, as in the picture, you have to select the two vertices on one side and press <kbd>G</kbd> two times to *Edge Slide*.

The vertices should slide on adjacent edges getting closer or further from each other.

Comment: Thank you, That has worked a treat and i have managed to get the effect i want now but have noticed that when i rotate the object in the viewport the vertex that i have moved is now sliding back and forth and effectively altering the effect.  I have tried saving the object but the vertex is still moving when rotating the object.  How do i make it so that the vertex stops moving around?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but in case you are in edit mode make sure you selected everything and then press R to rotate.

Comment: Hi Igor, I realised what was happening. When I performed the edge slide, I joined the vertices together but didn’t realise straight away that I hadn’t lined them up from all viewpoints. So, when I rotated the object I was seeing where it was not aligned yet from that particular viewing angle.  Newbie error I suppose. Thanks for your help 

Comment: Nice David! You're welcome 